# How to get the current working directory in Xquery?

Tags: marklogic

Im writing xquery script that need passing absolute path as an argument, this script will work perfectly if i put the project on the port root, but if i shift it to a sub-directory v2,v3 ... it will not work.

relative path will work perfect if the called function within the project root, but my called function is one of the Marklogic library like search:search. So i have to pass the absolute path to it.

This status make my code less dynamic, while the solution is to find a function that give me the current working directory so i can build the absolute path dynamically.

I found a module library called "file module" in the following link:

http://expath.org/spec/file#pr.current-dir

is there any function in Marklogic help me in this issue, or does they support this library?. If none of those options is available can anyone give me work around solution other than define global variable to handle the changes in the absolute path?

example:

```
<constraint name="Title">
            <custom facet="true">
                <parse apply="parse-facet-thesourous"
                       ns="......"
                       at="/utilites/custom-constrains.xqy"/>
                    .....
            </custom>
</constraint>
```

this is a snap shot of my options. this part passing the absolute path of custom-constrains file to search:search. now if i put the project on the weberver port root www.test.com:8050 every thing will work fine, but if i move the project inside sub directory www.test.com:8050/v1 the link in the option should be /v1/utilites/custom-constrains.xqy

on the other hand making the path relative is useless since this path will passed to an external marklogic module.

but if i can get in some way the current working directory absolute path or the uri of the current running script, then i can build the absolute path dynamically

Comment: It's unclear from your question what exactly you need the path for. Please post some example code that describes your problem.

Comment: I edited the querion and added an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [xdmp:function-module](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:function-module) might be of use for what you're attempting.

Clay

Comment: Thank you. This works for me without any pre-processing.  Having functions in  custom-constrains.xqy helps me in using this function :D.

Answer (score 3):

I can highly recommend not working from file-system (on a cluster, you would have to deploy on each server), and think in terms of database uris instead. Also, if requests are coming in from an app-server, you could leverage xdmp:get-request-path() to get some context of where you 'are'.

I would also not recommend creating search options dynamically from request input, a risk for code injection. Flexibility is one thing, security another..

HTH!

Comment: Thank you. This works for me with some string processing. However  i didn't read from file system ... all my scripts in module db.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that although you can use a relative path, it will be relative to the code executing that Search API extension, in `/Modules/Marklogic/appservices/search`.

For more clarification on path resolution, take a look at the [Application Developer's Guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/import_modules#id_45509), which goes into more detail but states that it will look:

1. In the Modules directory.
2. In a directory relative to the calling module.
3. Under the App Server root, which is either the specified directory in the Modules database (when the App Server is set to a Modules database) or the specified directory on the filesystem (when the App Server is set to find modules in the filesystem).

Since option #2 is out, either of the other two should work.

1. Move the module to the App Server root, or a path under the root.
2. Move the module to the `/Modules` directory, or a path under that root.

I agree with `@grtjn` that this is in almost every case a bad idea, but if you absolutely must check the filesystem, then your only option is `xdmp:filesystem-file-exists`. This will not give you the current filesystem path, but you could use it to check possible known paths:

```
let $location :=
  if (xdmp:filesystem-file-exists('/utilites/custom-constrains.xqy'))
  then '/utilites/custom-constrains.xqy'
  else if (xdmp:filesystem-file-exists('v1/utilites/custom-constrains.xqy'))
  then ...
  else ...
```

Comment: Thank you wst... option  1 is exactly what i did.  I was wonder if there is an xquery function that acting like _ _ DIR _ _ in php.

Comment: @AhmadTamimi See the updated solution for how to inspect the filesystem. I don't recommend doing it this way, however.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, i agree with u, this ways is not recommended, plus I'm not reading form file system all those scripts exists in the database.